# Toggle background color on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a quiz for test practice with lots of questions. Each question has five radio buttons, and among them there is only one right answer. In the first moment, the 5 options have a grey background. Once you click on a wrong option, it changes to red. If you click on another wrong option, it turns red and the previous one changes to grey. If you click on the right answer, it turns green and all the others stay grey.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {
    $("label").css("background-color", "red");
  });
  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $("label").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
```

```css
.option {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">
  <label class="option">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">
  <label class="option">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">
  <label class="option">Option 3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option4">
  <label class="option">Option 4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option5">
  <label class="option">Option 5</label>
</form>
```

How can I get there with JQuery?

Comment: check out my answer mate

Comment: Hello, Rani! I checked out your code, but it is not working here. I'm learning how to do that. I'm not sure if it is changing the label background. :(

Comment: try checking out the fiddle mate @Paulo

Comment: Thank you, Rani! But Ricky got what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh so you want to do is add class and not directly checking on the values of the radio buttons . . ok ok

Comment: Yes... hehehe... I think I didn't expressed my thought properly. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would need to change your markup.

Wrap each `input` inside the `label`.

Example:

```
<label class="option">
   <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">Option 1
</label>
```

Then change your CSS, to actually make the `input` clickable, but hidden:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

We will be using two helper classes as well:

```
.right {
  background-color: green;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Finally change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .addClass("wrong") //Add class wrong to the label
      .siblings().removeClass("right wrong"); // Remove classes from the other labels.
  });
  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .addClass("right") //Add class right to the label
      .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");// Remove classes from the other labels.
  });
});
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .addClass("wrong")
      .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
  });
  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .addClass("right")
      .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
  });
});
```

```css
.option {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.right {
  background-color: green;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">Option 3
  </label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option4">Option 4
  </label>
  <label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option5">Option 5
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0kexaguw/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").on('click',function() {
    if($(this).attr('value')=="wrong"){
    $(this).next().css("background", "red");
   }else{
      $(this).next().css("background", "green");
  }
  });

});
```

```css
.option {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">
  <label class="option">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">
  <label class="option">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">
  <label class="option">Option 3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option4">
  <label class="option">Option 4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option5">
  <label class="option">Option 5</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data-attributes` on this. Check my snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('attr') == 'wrong') {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    } else {
    $(this).css("background", "green");}
  });
});
```

```css
.option {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <input type="radio" name="option" data-attr="wrong" class="option1">
  <label class="option" data-attr="wrong">Option 1</label>
  
  <label class="option" data-attr="wrong">Option 2</label>
  
  <label class="option" data-attr="wrong">Option 3</label>
  
  <label class="option" data-attr="right">Option 4</label>
  
  <label class="option" data-attr="right">Option 5</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice! Do you know if it is possible to keep the grey? Like... when I click on option 2 it turns red, but the option 1 turns back grey.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos do you mean the last one click gets grey then the current click turns red or green?

Comment: Yes! I apologize you! I dont know English very well. I'm leraning a lot from you and the others. Thank you very much!